# Map thumb buttons to middle click in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mouse, x-windows

I've got a mouse with a thumb button that xev shows as button 9. I'd like to map it to be the same as a middle click (which, according to xev, is button 6).
How do I do it? I'm using Ubuntu Jaunty.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll be able to get this working with an xmodmap tweak. Have a look at the [Mouse section](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InputDevices) in the Ubuntu Community documentation, especially the entries for the Multi-buttoned Mouse and Logitech Marble Mouse USB.

You'll also find this [article](http://docs.hp.com/en/B1171-90076/ch09s01.html) on changing mouse buttons through xmodmap useful.

Comment: From this I got to this link, which right at the top shows what needs to be done:
http://fvue.nl/wiki/Configuring_my_5-button_mouse_in_X_Windows

Answer (score 1):

There are a ton of tutorials for this out on there on the internet.

This one is Ubuntu specific : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManyButtonsMouseHowto